# SQL: Text and datetime type in when-then statement

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have this

```
 case 
  when var1 is null then 'Some text'
  when var1 is not null then var2
 end AS [Some_Name],
```

var1 is an integer and var2 is a datetime and then I have this error: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or tiem from character string.

Who do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 case 
  when var1 is null     then 'Some text'
  when var1 is not null then  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), var2, 105)
 end AS [Some_Name]
```

In a case statement in case the return type should be the same. Just cast the datetime to varchar datatype. If you do not do an explicit cast then SQL Server will attempt to do an implicit case using the rules defined in data type precedence here: [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

To format the datetime variable in your desired format see here [`Sql Server Datetime Formats`](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: I want to conserve the 'dd-mm-yyyy' format... how do I do that?